# Cuando exporto de php a excel los valores con "barra slash" (/) me los toma como fecha

Tags: php, excel, exportar

Buen dia a todos,

Estoy realizando una exportación de un archivo de SQL a excel por medio de php, lo exporto en formato CSV y lo exportar, el problema es que al momento de abrir y revisar el documento descubrí que los datos que contiene barra slash(/) por ejemplo 1/2 o 25/9 aparecen como si fueran fecha (2-mar,25-sept) y no me sirve los necesito tal cual son; Descargue el archivo en txt y aparecen los datos bien el problema resulta solo cuando se exportan en csv y necesito que se descargue en csv.

les agradecería si me pudieran ayudar o aconsejar dejo el código con el que hago la exportación.

```
$serverName = "SERVERF";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"x","UID"=>"x","PWD"=>"x");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8');       


  
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="SalidaEIngreso.xls"');
$salida=fopen('php://output', 'w'); 
fputcsv($salida, array('Responsable_de_prestamo','CONSECUTIVO','FECHA_DE_SOLICITUD','DESCRIPCION_DE_SOLICITUD','TIPO_DE_UND_CONSERVADORA_GEN','TIPO_REQUERIMIENTO','ID_CINTA','CODIGO_ALTERNO','iIdentificacion_MYT_ECAT','tObservac','AÑO','iIdCaja','iIcajaNum','CAJA','tTipoFinal','ID_CARP_AZ_LIBRO','iIdentificacion_CP_AZ_LB_BOLSA','TOMO','FOLIOS','IMAGEN','MG','tEntrega','PRESTAMO_DE_CAJA','FECHA_DE_ENTREGA','OBSERVACIONBASE_CONSULTA_Y_PRESTAMO','SOLICITUD','DEVOLUCION','FECHA_DEVOLUCION','ESTADO','RESPONSABLE_INSERCION','FECHA_INSERCION','NOVEDADES_DEVOLUCION','CONTROL_DE_CALIDAD_1','RESPONSABLE_CONTROL_DE_CALIDAD_1','FECHA_CONTROL_DE_CALIDAD_1','NOVEDADES_CONTROL_DE_CALIDAD_1','CONTROL_DE_CALIDAD_2','RESPONSABLE_CONTROL_DE_CALIDAD_2','FECHA_CONTROL_DE_CALIDAD_2','NOVEDADES_CONTROL_DE_CALIDAD_2','OBSERVACIONES_CONTROL_DE_CALIDAD_2','tOrigen'),';');
$sql="SELECT * FROM Salida_E_Ingresos ";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );

while( $filaR = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        fputcsv($salida, array( 
            utf8_encode($filaR['Responsable_de_prestamo']),
            $filaR['CONSECUTIVO'],
            $filaR['FECHA_DE_SOLICITUD'],
            utf8_encode($filaR['DESCRIPCION_DE_SOLICITUD']),
            utf8_encode($filaR['TIPO_DE_UND_CONSERVADORA_GEN']),
            utf8_encode($filaR['TIPO_REQUERIMIENTO']),
            $filaR['ID_CINTA'],
            utf8_encode($filaR['CODIGO_ALTERNO']),
            $filaR['iIdentificacion_MYT_ECAT'],
            utf8_encode($filaR['tObservac']),
            $filaR['ANIO'],
            $filaR['iIdCaja'],
            $filaR['iIcajaNum'],
            $filaR['CAJA'],
            utf8_encode($filaR['tTipoFinal']),
            $filaR['ID_CARP_AZ_LIBRO'],
            $filaR['iIdentificacion_CP_AZ_LB_BOLSA'],
            $filaR['TOMO'],
            $filaR['FOLIOS'],
            $filaR['IMAGEN'],
            $filaR['MG'],
            utf8_encode($filaR['tEntrega']),
            $filaR['PRESTAMO_DE_CAJA'],
            $filaR['FECHA_DE_ENTREGA'],
            utf8_encode($filaR['OBSERVACIONBASE_CONSULTA_Y_PRESTAMO']),
            utf8_encode($filaR['SOLICITUD']),
            utf8_encode($filaR['DEVOLUCION']),
            $filaR['FECHA_DEVOLUCION'],
            utf8_encode($filaR['ESTADO']),
            utf8_encode($filaR['RESPONSABLE_INSERCION']),
            $filaR['FECHA_INSERCION'],
            utf8_encode($filaR['NOVEDADES_DEVOLUCION']),
            utf8_encode($filaR['CONTROL_DE_CALIDAD_1']),
            utf8_encode($filaR['RESPONSABLE_CONTROL_DE_CALIDAD_1']),
            $filaR['FECHA_CONTROL_DE_CALIDAD_1'],
            utf8_encode($filaR['NOVEDADES_CONTROL_DE_CALIDAD_1']),
            utf8_encode($filaR['CONTROL_DE_CALIDAD_2']),
            utf8_encode($filaR['RESPONSABLE_CONTROL_DE_CALIDAD_2']),
            $filaR['FECHA_CONTROL_DE_CALIDAD_2'],
            utf8_encode($filaR['NOVEDADES_CONTROL_DE_CALIDAD_2']),
            utf8_encode($filaR['OBSERVACIONES_CONTROL_DE_CALIDAD_2']),
            $filaR['tOrigen']),';'
        );      
    }
```

Comment: Al exportar, puedes configurar el tipo de columna que vas a asignar. Al ingresar "1/2" excel hace la correcta interpretación de que es una fecha lo que acabas de ingresar. Por que es el default de excel procesandolo. Ahora, si defines que esa columna es solo texto, solo ingresara como texto sin cambiar el formato.

Comment: Excorpion, perdona mi ignorancia pero no se como realizar la configuración de columna  por medio de php , te agradecería si me puedes indicar como o donde puedo consultar como realizar lo

Comment: Puedes googlear usando la exportación que tienes para saber como hacerlo. Asi no tener que reescribir guias de internet. Si algo falla de lo que sigas, puedes reconsultar acá.